# M query parameters in Power BI after publishing

Tags: powerbi

I created a power bi desktop  report using M query and created 2 dynamic parameters to send to stored procedure. When I publish this report on Power BI server then I dont see the Invoke function option for the user. How should the user get the option invoking function which uses the parameters? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When the report is published online, parameter values can be modified in the dataset's settings:

[image]

However, in most of the cases, this require reloading of the dataset, so your datasource must be available for Power BI Service to connect to it. This means that it should accept connections from the Internet, i.e. it must be publicly available, like in the cloud (e.g. Azure SQL Database), or [Power BI Gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/) is installed on it and properly configured.

Also take a look at [Edit parameter settings in the Power BI service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-parameters) article.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to allow end-users to send parameters to the backend data source. Parameters are only accessible to be managed by report designers.

Power Query is all about the data preparation which should be done behind the scenes. End-users are not allowed to even see it. Borrowing a metaphor from Ralph Kimball, restaurant diners can enjoy meals which are ready and served, but they are not allowed to wander into the backroom kitchen.

If you are looking for a client tool to allow users to communicate with the database directly, Power BI is not a right tool.